# p:dialog not hidden on validation failure

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am having a problem with not closing a PrimeFaces dialog. The input field 'username' is required:

```
<p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: "/>
<p:inputText id="username"
    value="#{employeeController.employee.username}" required="true"/>
```

I used the following code to prevent the dialog from closing if the field is empty:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="{employeeController.doSaveEmployee()}"
    oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('employeeAddDialog').hide()"
    update=":employeeForm"/>
```

But the dialog still closes whenever I click on 'Save' no matter if 'username' is filled or not. When I open the dialog again after closing the error message is displayed, so I know that the input validation works.

EDIT:

```
<p:dialog header="Create Employee" id="employeeAddDialog" widgetVar="employeeAddDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
  <p:outputPanel id="employeeDataCreate">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: " />
      <p:inputText id="username" value="#{employeeController.employee.username}" required="true" />

      <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: " />
      <p:password id="password" value="#{employeeController.employee.password}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
      <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{employeeController.doSaveEmployee()}" oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('employeeAddDialog').hide()" update=":employeeForm" />
      <p:commandButton value="Abort" oncomplete="PF('employeeAddDialog').hide()" />
    </h:panelGrid>
  </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Here is some more code. What else could be the cause for this problem?
`employeeForm` is just a `dataTable` that lists employees with their corresponding attributes.

EDIT2:

This code in `EmployeeController` yields the wanted behavior, but only if I remove `update=":employeeForm"` from the 'Save'-button

```
public void doSaveEmployee() {
    employee = employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
    employee = null;
    initNewEmployee();
    initList();
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('employeeAddDialog').hide();");
}
```

FINAL EDIT:

My dialog was closing because I updated the whole form. Changing `update=":employeeForm"` to `update=":employeeForm:employeeTable"` made things work like intended.

Comment: [mcve] please. Too many 'variables' outside this code that can be the cause of the behaviour you see

Comment: could you add the necessary parts of the EmployeeController source?

Comment: Don't post 'some more code' create a [mcve] for ypurself and post that

Comment: My problem is part of a relatively large spring application and I do not know how to post a runnable/verifiable example without posting walls of code.
I added doSaveEmployee() from EmployeeController with a semi-working solution from Abihabi87.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest make close operaction in `employeeController.doSaveEmployee()` after succes save action

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("PF('myDialogVar').hide();");
```

Comment: Thank you, that solution works well. The dialog now only closes if the required field is filled out. However, now another small problem occurs: The empty field message no longer shows up after clicking 'Save'. I'll have to look into that. But the main problem is solved.

Comment: I just realized that the solution only works if I remove update=":employeeForm" from the 'Save'-button. That explains why the message does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you are using oncomplete="args & amp; & amp; ...". I have never used that and works great.

```
oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('employeeAddDialog').hide()"
```

I use it like:

```
 oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('employeeAddDialog').hide()"
```

is this a question error?

Comment: This is more of a comment than answer. Please make it so