# Primefaces trigger onerror when exception occurs

Tags: jsf, primefaces

for a university project we have to create a website using primefaces and spring boot.
My problem lies in the error handling. I have a `p:dialog` which lets you edit user information. Once you save the user, the dialog should close. However, if the save is not successful a error message should appear and the user-edit-dialog should stay open.

This is the `commandButton` which triggers the save:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save"
    action="#{userDetailController.doSaveUser()}"
    ajax="true"
    validateClient="true"
    oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.closeForm) PF('userEditDialog').hide()"
    update=":userForm:usersTable msgs mainPanel" />
```

As you can see it's an ajax request so for handling exception we use the integrated `PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory`.

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

We are also displaying a dialog when a exception occurs.

```
<p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="at.qe.sepm.skeleton.utils.GeneralExpectedException" update="exceptionDialog"
                        onexception="PF('exceptionDialog').show();" />
<p:dialog id="exceptionDialog"
          header="#{pfExceptionHandler.exception.type}"
          widgetVar="exceptionDialog"
          resizable="false">
    Message: #{pfExceptionHandler.message}
    <p:separator rendered="#{exceptionHelperBean.displayException(pfExceptionHandler.exception)}" />
    <h:outputText rendered="#{exceptionHelperBean.displayException(pfExceptionHandler.exception)}"
                  value="#{pfExceptionHandler.formattedStackTrace}"
                  escape="false" />
</p:dialog>
```

My problem has to do with this line `oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.closeForm) PF('userEditDialog').hide()"`. The user-edit-dialog will only be closed when the closeForm flag is set. Which is done on the server:

```
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam("closeForm", true);
```

From my understanding from other frameworks, when a exception occurs the server returns HTTP 500 and the `onerror` callback on the `commandButton` triggers.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Ideally i don't want the `oncomplete` callback to trigger in the first place. I also tried using the `onsuccess` callback which doesn't get triggered at all, even if the request returns HTTP 200.

*edit:*

This is the `doSaveUser` methods inside the `userDetailController`:

```
public void doSaveUser() throws Exception {
    user = this.userService.saveUser(user);

    PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam("closeForm", true);
}
```

It internally calls the userServices save method where i manually throw the exception:

```
public User saveUser(User user) throws Exception {
    if (user.isNew()) {
        User existingUser = userRepository.findFirstByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if(existingUser != null) {
            throw new GeneralExpectedException("User with name " + user.getUsername() + " already exists",
                    ExceptionType.WARNING);
        }
```

I hope this makes the problem more clear. Saving a user which already exists throws a exception - so the user edit dialog should stay open, in order to make adjustments. However, I also want the Exception dialog to trigger so you can see why saving is not possible.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [p:dialog not hidden on validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890627/pdialog-not-hidden-on-validation-failure)

Comment: _"From my understanding from other frameworks, when a exception occurs the server returns HTTP 500 and the onerror callback on the commandButton triggers."_ Wrong assumption. Yes, if other frameworks do not have exception handling in place this happens, but the same is true for JSF. If there is no exception handling anywhere an http 500 is used.

Comment: Even though I do not directly see the cause of your problem (there is no [mcve] which) You seem to have some mixed up understanding of errors, errors, caught exceptions and uncaught exceptions. So I'll try to write something up over the coming days.

Comment: @Selaron Unfortunately not. I am using client side validation, so no problem there.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your help, i extended my question so can get a clearer picture of whats going on.